# Read data from excel file column wise how can I change it to row wise

Tags: java, excel, xssf

I have written to get in column wise how to get this code into row wise

```
XSSFSheet TcSheet = workbook.getSheet(TestCaseName);
int TcRow = TcSheet.getLastRowNum();
int TcCol = TcSheet.getRow(1).getLastCellNum();

data = new Object[TcCol][TcRow + 1];
for (int i = 0; i <= TcRow; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < TcCol; j++) {
        Cell Cell = TcSheet.getRow(i).getCell(j);
        TcSheet.getRow(i).getCell(j).setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        data[j][i] = TcSheet.getRow(i).getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
    }
}
return data;
```

Comment: Step 1: Indent your code properly. Step 2: Read the [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) Step 3: Explain what you mean, because in the end you already iterate `rows` as well

Comment: @XtremeBaumer This code reads the data from the excel file column wise what edit must be done to make it read data from the excel file row wise

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i <= TcRow; i++) {` this code should tell you, that you already iterate "row wise". You have to specify exactly what you want. You actually iterate all cells right now which means rows as well as columns. Maybe just switch the 2 for-loops if that is what you want

Comment: what changes to be done in the loops to read the data vise versa

Comment: None, just switch the 2 loops

Comment: I told you exactly what you need to do. If you can't perform these changes (switching 2 lines), then you are probably wrong in programming

Comment: Cooldown :) and thanks for your help